# No suitable constructor exists to convert from "dumb pointer" to "smart pointer"

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr

```
struct A
{
    A(int a);
};

struct B
{
    B();
    void b(std::shared_ptr<A> a);
};

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    B b;
    b.b(&a);
}
```

So I got this error, sorry guys it's my frist time with the smart pointers!!

Error:

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from `"A *"` to `"std::tr1::shared_ptr<A>"`

How do I fix this problem!?

Comment: My guess would be a constructor

Comment: The shared_ptr is **specifically** designed not to allow this! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others already ranted on the design error of your code, but not the real problem why the code doesn't even compile. `shared_ptr` has a constructor that accepts a raw pointer, but it is marked as `explicit`, which means you have to explicitly write out that you want to construct a `shared_ptr` instance. What your function call tries, is to do that construction implicitly, which isn't allowed because of the explicit keyword.

The following will compile but give undefined behaviour because the `shared_ptr` will (try to) `delete` an object which resides on the stack and is as such not deleteable:

```
b.b(shared_ptr<A>(&a)); // explicit construction
```

A special trait of `shared_ptr` is that you can pass the constructor a deleter, which will be called when the owned pointer should be deleted. You can just write and use a "noop" deleter, which does just nothing; the following will not invoke undefined behaviour and will not try to delete the stack variable:

```
// outside of main
void noop_deleter(A*){/*do nothing*/}

 // call...
b.b(shared_ptr<A>(&a, noop_deleter));
```

And there actually is a use for this, if you have a library API that absolutely wants a `shared_ptr` but you want to call it with a stack variable. The design of that API is another thing though...

Answer (score 4):

The entire point of a smart pointer is to have ownership. That is, *it's* responsible for the deallocation of whatever it's pointing it. It simply doesn't make sense to try to tell it to manage something that's already being managed by a completely different system.

In your case, `a` is already being automatically managed, why would you want to *also* be managed by a smart pointer? Even if that worked, you'd just be setting yourself for deleting it twice, which is UB.

*Either* give it something to own, like `new A(1)`, or change `b` to operate on something it doesn't own.

Comment: "is to have ownership" ... it largely depends on the type of smart pointer and basically making the disctinction between all the ownership policies is mandatory for a proper understanding of smart pointers. with shared_ptr we have shared ownership, with auto_ptr we have strict ownership to one entity w/ transfer of ownership upon copy, etc.

Comment: @AlexandreAbreu : I understand that you're only picking on the wording of that particular phrase, but I think his larger point is that giving any smart pointer the address of an object allocated on the stack will result in UB.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, and in each case they own their resource, hence "to have ownership". The various ways they might manage that ownership has nothing to do with the previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

std::tr1::shared_ptr has one constructor that allows to pass down a given raw pointer. So if you had a pointer to A, you would do something like:

std::shared_ptr (pMyA)

but in your case, your pointer to A points to an automatic variable NOT to a dynamically allocated memory resource that can be deleted after usage.

Something like this would be a better use case:

```
class B
{
  void b (shared_ptr <A> pA) {}
}

int main ()
{
  shared_ptr<A> pA (new A);
  B b;
  b.b (pA);
  ...
}
```