# Smart pointers: no suitable constructor exists to convert from derived_object* to std::shared_ptr<abstract_base_object>

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have just started learning about smart pointers and I'm having some trouble implementing them.

I'm writing code for a board game that has an abstract base class for pieces and for example one derived class for a piece:

```
class pieces {
public:
    virtual ~pieces() {};
};
class piece1:public pieces {
private:
    std::string id{ "" };
    std::string team{ "" };
public: 
    piece1(std::string identification, std::string red_or_blue_team);
    ~piece1() { std::cout << "destructor called." << std::endl; }
};
```

There's also a separate abstract class for the board game itself and for example a derived class for some specific board game e.g chess:

```
typedef std::map < int, std::shared_ptr<pieces> > grid;

class board_game {
protected:
    grid the_board;
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<pieces> create_piece(std::string type, int id, std::string team) = 0;
};
class chess: public board_game {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<pieces> create_piece(std::string type, int id, std::string team);
};
```

The goal is to create shared pointers to a value on a map container which will then be moved around in ownership as the piece is moved by other methods in the class (not shown).

So as a starting point I have the function create_piece:

```
std::shared_ptr<pieces> chess::create_piece(std::string type, int id, std::string team)
{
    if (type == "piece1_type") {
        return new piece1(id,team);
    }
}
```

This returns an error on the line `return new piece1(id,team);` 
Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "piece1*" to "std::shared_ptr"
and also :
'return': cannot convert from 'flag *' to 'std::shared_ptr'.

I assume the solution to this has something to do with changing my implementation of the parameterized constructor for piece1 but I'm really not sure how to do that. 
The constructor for piece1:

```
flag::flag(std::string identification, std::string red_or_blue_team)
{
    id = identification;
    team = red_or_blue_team;

}
```

I've seen there's a similar [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132204/no-suitable-constructor-exists-to-convert-from-dumb-pointer-to-smart-pointer) here but I couldnt quite apply it to my own problem effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly converting a raw pointer to a smart pointer would result in many potential problems, e.g. that raw pointer that points to memory that is already owned/managed by a smart pointer, that has automatic storage duration, or that is manually managed, would be passed to a smart pointer for managing, and that would result into double frees.

As of that such an implicit "conversion" is not allowed.

Instead of `return new piece1(id,team);` you would write `return std::make:shared<piece1>(id,team);`

If you really want to manage the memory of a raw pointer using a smart point then this has to be done explicitly `std::smart_ptr<piece1>(rawPointer)`. This explicit conversion is normally only needed if you work with a library that does not use smart pointers and returns an owning raw pointer to you. This should never be done for objects that you create in your code.

Comment: thank you that works! I have a follow up question that I was wondering if you could answer. Is there some other (better) way I could design my program such that i didnt have to use make_shared or is make_shared the standard way things like this are done?

Comment: @user3626437 `make_shared` is the standard way to create a shared ptr.